# passing view model from page to user control in windows store app

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

In a Windows Store split app, I want to pass a view model from a page to a user control.  The scenario is that I want to reuse some common xaml in multiple pages, using a UserControl like a view.

In the main page:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    ... >
  <views:MyUserControlView Model="{Binding ViewModel}" />
...
```

In the user control code:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControlView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(MenuSource),
        typeof(MyUserControlView), null);
    ...
    public ModelType Model
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(ModelProperty) as ModelType ;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ModelProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

The Model setter is never called.  How do I hook up the user control to the parent page's view model?

Or, is there a better way to implement shared views for use in pages?

Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct binding would be:

```
<views:MyUserControlView Model="{Binding}" />
```

You've already set `DataContext` for the page above. All bindings are relative to the current `DataContext`.

The setter still won't be called, though. It is just a wrapper to access the `DependencyProperty` from code. Binding will call `SetValue` directly.

Depending on your requirements you might not even need to define your own `Model` `DependencyProperty`. Each control automatically inherits `DataContext` from its parent control. In your example above the user control already has its `DataContext` set to the same view model as the page.